# StandardOutput stream staying open after process exits

Tags: c#, .net, process, adb

When working with processes in .NET, I have become accustomed to the behavior that the exiting of the process will end the output of StandardOutput and StandardError. However, I have found one exe where this does not seem to be the case, and *I would like to understand whether and why my assumption is wrong*.

Here is code that reproduces the issue I am seeing. It uses a specific version of the Android Debug Bridge executable (available from https://hostr.co/bBxxj7gFfMlW).

```
// before running, terminate any adb.exe processes on the system
// adb.exe's initial run leaves behind a background daemon that changes the
// behavior of future adb.exe runs

var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Users\[my user]\Downloads\ADB-1.0.31.zip\adb.exe",
        Arguments = "connect 127.0.0.1",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
    }
};
process.Start();

var tasks = new Task[] 
{
    Task.Run(() => { process.WaitForExit(); Console.WriteLine("Process exited"); }),
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int b;
        while ((b = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"STDOUT: {b} ({(char)b})");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("STDOUT: DONE");
    }),
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int b;
        while ((b = process.StandardError.BaseStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"STDERR: {b} ({(char)b})");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("STDERR: DONE");
    })
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

I would expect to see that the process runs for a bit, produces some output (logged byte-by-byte to console), and then exits. Once the process exits, the tasks that are reading from the stream should get -1 back and exit themselves.

All of this happens, EXCEPT that after the process exits the streams stay open and the reader tasks hang indefinitely on ReadByte().

**EDIT:**

Did a bit more digging and found some code in the implementation of Process that underscores my expectation that the stream should close when the process dies. In `WaitForExit()`, if you are asynchronously streaming output using `BeginOutputDataReadLine()`, the wait call blocks on making sure that the async output readers received EOF ([code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,2454)). If the above example is modified to use:

`process.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();`

instead of having an explicit task that reads bytes from StandardOutput, then the WaitForExit() task never returns (although polling `process.HasExited` returns false after a while)!

Comment: use the latest official binary from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip

Comment: Wrong.  A stream will close under two conditions.  1) The application that opened the stream closes it.  2) The stream gets an EOF.  When windows abort a task it closes the stream but doesn't send EOF. So the stream stays open.  Other issue is EOF is a character and when sending binary there is no EOF character.  So when sending binary always preceded the binary data with a byte count so receiving end knows where end of data is located.  When sending multiple blocks then you must have a command and a byte count so receiver know when last block occurs.

Comment: @AlexP. yep, I'm not having any issues with the latest; I'm instead trying to shore up generic process-handling code to work in a variety of situations.

Comment: @jdweng very interesting. Can you point me to some documentation or post that explains this in greater detail? I'm curious what you mean by "windows closes the stream ... so the stream stays open".